# fusion360/electronic ULP polyPour() contour()

Tags: fusion360

I have a ULP for PCBs that worked for me in EAGLECAD. Now I tried to see if it works for me on fusion360/electronic and after various errors I realized that a part of the program that concerns:

`polyPours() -> contours()`

I have done many tests and variations, I have already read and reread the [link](https://help.autodesk.com/view/fusion360/ENU/?guid=ECD-ULP-POLYPOUR) and I have identified the part that doesn't work; in eagle's ULP instead of `polypour` there was `polygons` then everything is the same. In the fusion360 ULP, it doesn't fit into the `P.contours(W) part` and I don't understand what I have to do to run the program.

This is the part that doesn't work; If you want I will also attach the entire ULP

```
board(B){
    B.signals(S)
        {if (S.name == OutlinesSignalName)
            {S.polyPours(P)
                {P.wires(W)
                    {x1 = min(x1, W.x1);
                     x2 = max(x2, W.x1);
                     y1 = min(y1, W.y1);
                     y2 = max(y2, W.y1);}
                P.contours(W)
                     {WireX1[WireCount] = W.x1;
                       WireY1[WireCount] = W.y1;
                       WireX2[WireCount] = W.x2;
                       WireY2[WireCount] = W.y2;
                       ++WireCount;}}
               break;}
          }
}`
```

I don't understand the function or is it a bug?